# Proving with Cauchy Schwarz that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}w_j\phi_j(t)$ converges if $\sum_j w^2_j/\lambda_j<\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, probability-theory, inequality

> Suppose that the covariance kernel $K$ of the Gaussian process W={W_t:t\in T}, defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{U},P)$, can be written in the form $$K(s,t)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda_j\phi_j(s)\phi_j(t)$$

> for positive numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...$ and arbitary functions $\phi_j:T\to\mathscr{R}$ where the series is assumed to converge pointwise on $T\times T$. The converegence on the diagonal implies:

> $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\lambda_j\phi^2_j(t)<\infty$$ for all $t\in T$. Then by the Cauchy Schwartz inequality the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}w_j\phi_j(t)$ converges absoluttely for every sequence $w_j$ of numbers with $\sum_j w^2_j/\lambda_j<\infty$.

I have tried on many ways to apply Cauchy Scharz to prove the sequence $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}w_j\phi_j(t)$ is convergent. I tried $\langle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}w_j\phi_j(t),\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\lambda_j}\phi_j(t)\rangle$ and then isolate $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}w_j\phi_j(t)$ but it did not work.

I know that this may be simple to a point the author does not show it, but I cannot see how to prove that the series $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}w_j\phi_j(t)$ converges if $\sum_j w^2_j/\lambda_j<\infty$ .

**Question**:

Can someone help me prove the claim?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty w_j\varphi_j(t)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \frac{w_j}{\sqrt{\lambda_j}}(\sqrt{\lambda_j}\varphi_j(t)).$$ By Cauchy-Schwarz, $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty |w_j\varphi_j(t)|\leq\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty w_j^2/\lambda_j\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j\varphi^2_j(t)\right)^{1/2}.$$